# C# Selenium Start JavaScript to Auto Download Images

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to execute some JavaScript when an image element exists
In theory the script should create a download link, click it (Chrome set to auto save) then click the next img if that exists

Obviously not every page has an image so I need to navigate to the first page however the JavaScript below nether fires and there isn't anything in the console

Is there a way to manually start & stop the JavaScript or am I doing something wrong?

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    string ChromeDriverPath = "D:\\Software\\chromedriver_win32";
    string currentUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument($"user-data-dir={currentUser}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");

    
    //Creates the ChomeDriver object, Executes tests on Google Chrome

    var driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverPath, options);
    
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com/index.html/");
    // 
    driver.ExecuteScript(@"window.addEventListener('load', function () {
console.log('All assets are loaded')
var thepic = document.getElementById('thepic');
if (typeof (thepic) != 'undefined' && thepic != null) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = thepic.src;
    link.download = thepic.title;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    var NextImg = document.getElementsByName('next');
    NextImg.click();
}
})");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

FYI: The Website Requires user to login & is generated by PHP so you can't send the img SRC to WebClient to download it

Comment: don't think that'll work... (the browser will probably display, not download)  but you can just grab all the src attributes and then send your own requests to get them.  No need to run javascript for this.  If the <img> elements have "src" attributes, then that should work, since there's no check for authorization there... it's just a path to a resource.  Another option would be to take screenshots of the elements.